# new version of ios application error

Tags: ios, ios8

I have a problem with iOS application, that I uploaded to Itunes for publishing in the store. Apple began the typical process of approval, but errors appeared.

The application worked in my test enviroment. No problems. When the Apple revision process began they told me that the application doesn't start.

When the application start the error is:
        There is a new version of AppName 
         to download. Press OK button to
           download it in the AppStore

But:
1) The application is the only version. Is a new app, never uploaded before to Apple Store.
2) When i push the OK, the app closes. So, no way to run the app even with that.

I search through forums and internet with no luck. I don't know where to search about this problem.

For more confusion, after the test from Apple, in my test enviroment i can reproduce the error. I don't know if i did anything wrong in the middle or something change on app version check from Apple.

I contact Apple in the previous days to give more info about the problem, but the only that they say is "the application does not work"

Can you give me an advice?... what info you need? (logs, etc)
Thanks to point me in the right direction.

Comment: what do you mean by: `application that I uploaded to Itunes Connect for testing` I tunes connect is for submitting apps to the app store. Not testing. Are you trying to use TestFlight

Comment: @logixologist: you can upload builds to iTunes Connect and not submit them for review. During this period, you can assign testers.

Comment: @IanMacDonald oh that explains it. I haven't used TestFlight from Apple yet.

Comment: I rewrite the problem to be more accurate. Sorry, my english is not my best. Hope that you can help me.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the message? how does it look like? is it an ios alert or something from a 3rd party lib?

Comment: @Hannes: Sorry, but the page does not allow me to upload images. Is a typical iOS Alert. And the message is: "There is a new version of AppName to download. Press OK button to download it in the AppStore". Thanks!